# Как лучше всего получить свойство из *.property файла в jsf?

Tags: java, spring, jsf, properties

Каким образом лучше всего получать свойства из *.property файлов на jsf странице?

Answer (score 0):

Можно в faces-config.xml определить глобальный ресурс

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
     <application>
      <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>com.example.messages</base-name>
        <var>msg</var>
       </resource-bundle>
     </application>
</faces-config>
```

а можно определить локальный на конкретной странице:

```
<f:loadBundle basename="com.example.messages" var="msg"/>
```

И потом обращаться по ключу

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg['someProperyName']}" />
```